# How to REALLY request a folder not a file in rebol?

Tags: rebol

Request-file/path returns a folder and files in a block but still requires to select at least a file: it isn't possible to select a folder only.

Update: request-dir exists but it's not the windows dialog, I prefer windows dialog like request-file, isn't it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,

```
request-dir
```

Comment: oh yes I forgot this one :) but it's not the windows dialog, I prefer windows dialog like request-file, isn't it possible ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible without using win32 API (for windows)